# kotlin - unknown syntax in Jetpack Owl Example

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose, declaration

trying to find some direction on how to select multiple items in a lazy column, I have found the following code in Owl Jetpack Compose example (Onboarding.kt).

```
...    
val (selected, onSelected) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
...
```

Even if I'm able to use the code by myself, I really not able to decode the syntax of this val declaration.
I wasn't able to find anything in kotlinlang.org site (the nearest topic I've found is about Destructuring declarations).
Could someone help me to understand it and/or point me to relevant documentation?

Comment: Well, it *is* a destructuring declaration. You already found the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is Destructuring as you mentioned in question which is expclicitly as

```
val (selected: Boolean, onSelected: (Boolean) -> Unit) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Which requires 2 components of targetted class.
`(val num1:Int, val num2:Int) = Pair(1,2)` is an example

With MutableState

```
@Stable
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

You need to add `T` type and a lambda that takes T as param and returns unit.

And inside `SnapshotImpl` source code of MutableState it's used as

```
override operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit = { value = it }
```

so anything you set using this lambda is assigned to value `T`