# State hosting in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am learning [State hosting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) in jetpack compose. I am trying to separate my variable in single function and view logic to separate function. But I am getting weird issue in my code. Can someone guide me on this?

**PulsePressure**

```
@Composable
fun PulsePressure() {
    var systolicTextFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
    }
    var isSystolicTextFieldValueError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var diastolicTextFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
    }
    var isDiastolicTextFieldValueError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    InputWithUnitContainer(
        systolicTextFieldValue,
        isError = {
            isSystolicTextFieldValueError = it
        },
        incrementTextFieldValue = {
            systolicTextFieldValue = it
        })
    InputWithUnitContainer(
        diastolicTextFieldValue,
        isError = {
            isDiastolicTextFieldValueError = it
        },
        incrementTextFieldValue = {
            diastolicTextFieldValue = it
        }
    )
}
```

**InputWithUnitContainer**

```
@Composable
fun InputWithUnitContainer(
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue,
    isError: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    incrementTextFieldValue: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
) {
    val maxLength = 4
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            singleLine = true,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.text.length <= maxLength) {
                    incrementTextFieldValue(it)
                }
                isError(false)
            },
            isError = isError,
            textStyle = RegularSlate20
        )
    }
}
```

**Error on Textfield**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isError` parameter in `TextField` is a Boolean.

**Change 1**

You have to change

```
var isDiastolicTextFieldValueError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

to

```
var (isDiastolicTextFieldValueError, updateIsDiastolicTextFieldValueError) = rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(
        false
    )
}
```

This gives the value and a function to update the value.

**Change 2**

Then pass both the value and the method to the composable.

Usage

```
InputWithUnitContainer(
    textFieldValue = diastolicTextFieldValue,
    isError = isDiastolicTextFieldValueError,
    updateIsError = updateIsDiastolicTextFieldValueError,
    incrementTextFieldValue = {
        diastolicTextFieldValue = it
    }
)
```

Method signature change

```
@Composable
fun InputWithUnitContainer(
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue,
    isError: Boolean,
    updateIsError: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    incrementTextFieldValue: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
) {
    ...
}
```

**Change 3**

Update the usage

```
TextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    singleLine = true,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.text.length <= maxLength) {
            incrementTextFieldValue(it)
        }
        updateIsError(false)
    },
    isError = isError,
    textStyle = TextStyle(),
)
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. what do you call this method `var (isDiastolicTextFieldValueError, updateIsDiastolicTextFieldValueError) = rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(
        false
    )
}`. I want to learn about this. I know delate property but what do we call this?

Comment: This is de structuring declaration of variables. Reference - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

Comment: @vivekmodi you can check this answer about destructuring with MutableState https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970915/5457853